# WHMCS Custom Module - How to activate product addon

Tags: php, whmcs

I have created my own custom module using the provisioning module provided by WHMCS.
I want to have a process where when the payment has been made, the module have a function to activate the product addon (because the product is onetime payment while the addon is anually which only billed at the end of the year).
Is there any hook th![enter image description here][1]at I could use to call the add on function?!
Below is my custom module list of functions, so im not really sure where can i start hooking it to the 'add on activation function' or how to do it.. Please help :)

```
function BrasstaxCorporate_ConfigOptions() {...
function BrasstaxCorporate_CreateAccount($params) {...
function BrasstaxCorporate_TerminateAccount($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_SuspendAccount($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_UnsuspendAccount($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_ChangePassword($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_ChangePackage($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_ClientArea($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_AdminLink($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_LoginLink($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_genkey($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_uninstall($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_ClientAreaCustomButtonArray() {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_AdminCustomButtonArray() {.
function BrasstaxCorporate_extrapage($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_UsageUpdate($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_AdminServicesTabFields($params) {..
function BrasstaxCorporate_AdminServicesTabFieldsSave($params) {..
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at WHMCS' licensing addon - this would definitely do what you are looking for, though the code is encoded.
http://docs.whmcs.com/Licensing_Addon

That being said, to accomplish the same thing, you would want to specify which addon to use, and in the CreateAccount function, grab the serviceid they pass you and use a local API command on the AddonAdd function:
http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks:Addons#AddonAdd

Essentially this allows you to add an addon when the product is created.  You will also want to use the AddonSuspended, AddonTerminated etc for the appropriate Product Actions in your module.